# Anagram program with sentences

Tags: python

I have a question about the following code:

```
str1 = "Race"
str2 = "Care"

# convert both the strings into lowercase
str1 = str1.lower()
str2 = str2.lower()

# check if length is same
if(len(str1) == len(str2)):

    # sort the strings
    sorted_str1 = sorted(str1)
    sorted_str2 = sorted(str2)

    # if sorted char arrays are same
    if(sorted_str1 == sorted_str2):
        print(str1 + " and " + str2 + " are anagram.")
    else:
        print(str1 + " and " + str2 + " are not anagram.")

else:
    print(str1 + " and " + str2 + " are not anagram.")
```

`"Race"` and `"Care"` are now anagrams, but how to make an anagram with sentences?

For example:

```
str1 = "Race is good"  
str2 = "Careisgood"
```

They are also an anagram, but it gives that it is not an anagram. I think it's because of the spaces. How to skip the spaces?

Comment: `str2 = str2.lower().replace(" ", "")` on both str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove spaces from a string, you can use the replace(" ", "") method.

```
str1 = "Race is good"
str2 = "Careisgood"

# convert both the strings into lowercase
str1 = str1.lower().replace(" ", "")
str2 = str2.lower().replace(" ", "")

# check if length is same
if(len(str1) == len(str2)):

    # sort the strings
    sorted_str1 = sorted(str1)
    sorted_str2 = sorted(str2)

    # if sorted char arrays are same
    if(sorted_str1 == sorted_str2):
        print(str1 + " and " + str2 + " are anagram.")
    else:
        print(str1 + " and " + str2 + " are not anagram.")

else:
    print(str1 + " and " + str2 + " are not anagram.")
```